# Infinite loops - top or bottom?

Tags: c++, c, coding-style

In the spirit of questions like [Do your loops test at the top or bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224059/do-your-loops-test-at-the-top-or-bottom):

Which style do you use for an *infinite* loop, and why?

- while (true) { }
- do { } while (true);
- for (;;) { }
- label: ... goto label;

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224204/why-use-infinite-loops

Comment: possible duplicate of [Endless loop in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186809/endless-loop-in-c-c)

Comment: It's popular in some circles to do `#define ever ;;` just so you can then do `for(ever){ … }`.

Answer (score 36):

```
while(true) {}
```

It seems to convey the meaning of the loop most effectively.

Answer (score 22):

```
for (;;)
{
    /* No warnings are generated about constant value in the loop conditional
       plus it is easy to change when you realize you do need limits */ 
}
```

Answer (score 13):

```
#define forever for(;;)

forever {
    /*stuff*/
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
while(1)
{
//do it 
}
```

That's how I roll.

Answer (score 6):

I like to use the **for(;;)** approach because the **MSVC++** compiler *complains* about while loop approach:

```
void main()
{
  while(1) // test.cpp(5) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
  {
  }

  for(;;)
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: I like that it complains - gives a cue that, yes, it is indeed an infinite loop.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer `while(1)` or `while(true)` -- it's the clearest.  `do { } while(true)` seems like needless obfuscation.  Likewise, `for(;;)` can be confusing to people that have never seen it before, whereas `while(true)` is very intuitive.  And there's absolutely no reason to do `label: ... goto label;`, it's just more confusing.

Comment: 'while (true)' could be confusing as 'for (;;)' if you think about it too long. Under what circumstances does the while exit?  Maybe a '#define forever while(true)' would give us a more English keyword.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, Adam. for (;;) is cool in a dirty C kind of way, but I wouldn't bring it out in public.

Answer (score 3):

```
10 some l33t code
20 goto 10
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually use `for(;;) { }` which I always think of as "for-ever".

Some languages offer a `repeat { }` construct which will natively loop forever. I find the `for(;;) { }` construct visually the most similar to this because it is so different from the normal `for()` construct. This is an important attribute for an infinite loop that `while(1) { }` doesn't really have.

Comment: Which languages have a repeat keyword?

Comment: Dunno, but Perl 6 has loop { } for the same idea.

Comment: Icon, Logo and Rexx are the first that come to mind. There are others.

Comment: R has repeat { } too.

Answer (score 3):

Infinite tail-recursion ;)

It's somewhat compiler-dependant...

Comment: Only if you use a niche compiler. The most important ones [do it as optimizations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125/which-if-any-c-compilers-do-tail-recursion-optimization).

Answer (score 3):

I use `for (;;)` in C-style languages and `while true` in languages that don't support that construct.

I learned the `for (;;)` method in K&R and it has always felt like idiomatic C to me.

Answer (score 2):

Let the flaming begin...

If the loop is a *true* infinite loop (i.e. there is no break condition -- only an external event can terminate the thread's/process' execution), then I actually prefer the label and `goto`. Here's why:

First, the use of `while`, `for`, and `do ... while`, all imply that the loop might terminate. Even if the terminating condition is never achievable, the *syntactical meaning* of these constructs is that there **is** some termination condition.

Second, using a loop construct introduces an extra level of indentation. I hate indentation that's not necessary. It wastes valuable columnar real-estate.

Third, the only *true* infinite loop is the one that *unconditionally* jumps back to the beginning of the loop. Only `goto` fits that purpose exactly.

The truth is I don't really care that much about it. They all get the job done and most will result in the exact same assembly instructions anyway. **However**, the assembly that's generated will in all probability be an unconditional jump (if you're optimizer is worth a damn), which maps directly to which C construct, kids?  That's right... your old friend `goto`.

Answer (score 1):

When writing code for myself I use for(;;). Other people tend to be confused by its syntax and so for code that other people must see/use, I use while(true).

Comment: If other people are confused by that syntax, they need to learn the programming language better.  It's hard to imagine someone being caught off-guard by something in the core language syntax...

Answer (score 1):

offtopic: if you think about what you are trying to express, you usually won't need an infinite loop.

Comment: Not necessarily. I've run across many cases where an infinite loop (with or without a `break`) is the cleanest way to express something.

Comment: Ya, I have observed the same thing.  I pop in an infinite loop, and morph the code to meet the unit test. Before I can blink, I see that it can be turned into a normal loop construct.

Answer (score 1):

`for (;;)` is what I usually see.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(;;);
```

Filler text.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite loops are a bad idea, but in practice that doesn't always hold up.

I prefer while(1) { } but make sure something within the loop can cause it to break out.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `while() {}`, but after learning that `for(;;) {}` isn't some sort of crazy invalid syntax, I'll be sure to use the more unique option.

Differentiates infinite loops from actual conditionals, you see.

Answer (score 0):

I now prefer the "`for (;;)`" idiom because it seems to 'stick out' more.  I used to use the "`while (true)`" idiom because I thought it expressed intent better, but I've switched over because I think the "`for (;;)`" idiom is well known enough to adequately express intent as well as I believe it's better by being more visible.

Kind of like how Stroustrup made the new casts in C++ purposefully ugly - so they stick out.