# In which case should infinite loops be used?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

Infinite loops are useful in games. Often, you want the game to keep going until something happens within the loop that would stop it. But in which other case can infinite loops be used?

Comment: One case I can think of is a generator that yields elements of an infinite series.

Comment: When you wish to repeat one or more actions until some condition is true (or false), as opposed to when iterating over a sequence has completed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to read [`this post on Quora`](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-practical-uses-of-infinite-loops), and [`this other`](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-use-of-an-infinite-loop-in-a-program) too.

> *Most GUIs are based on infinite loops, often called a run loop or event loop. After setup, the main thread calls a non-returning function.*
>
> (From the second link)

This [`other one`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224204/why-use-infinite-loops) from Stack Overflow may be useful.

> *All the operating systems run in an infinite loop as it does not exist after performing some task.*
>
> (From [`JavatPoint`](https://www.javatpoint.com/infinite-loop-in-c))