# Best infinite loop

Tags: c, optimization, loops, infinite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [while (1) Vs. for (;;) Is there a speed difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885908/while-1-vs-for-is-there-a-speed-difference)

Hi,

Which is better,faster and more optimized way to implement infinite loop - for(;;) or while(1)? and why?

Comment: Isn't an optimized infinite loop an oxymoron?

Comment: Seriously?  Look at the compiler output.

Comment: Exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885908/while-1-vs-for-is-there-a-speed-difference/

Comment: I'm guessing its either while(1) or more likely, they are the same.

If you're curious why not write a quick test prog to see for yourself?

Comment: Near-duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224138/infinite-loops-top-or-bottom

Comment: With any sane compiler, they are equivalent.

Comment: @Stephen: I'm curious to hear more about the *in* sane compilers...

Comment: @fire.eagle, modern Intel processors can execute an infinite loop in two second.  With a suboptimal implementation of an infinite loop, it would take minutes!  So one has to choose carefully.

Comment: @Pavel Shved: Ah. Well, that's what I get for using AMD. :P

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In any normal compiler, there should be absolutely no difference. For example, here's what `LLVM-clang` generates (with the `-O3` flag) for `while (1) {}`:

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB0_1:
    jmp .LBB0_1
```

Note the `jmp .LBB0_1` part, which is the actual infinite loop. For the `for (;;)` kind, it generates *absolutely the same code*.

You can also try with other compilers for fun, but it's best just stop worrying about it.

---

OK, I just had to try with `gcc` as well:

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
.L2:
    jmp .L2
```

Comment: Ya, I also tried the while(1) and for(;;) with gcc and got no difference.

Comment: +1 for using Clang instead of GCC.

Answer (score 52):

I prefer `for(;;)` because it doesn't test anything and semantically this is what you mean. It doesn't make so much sense to keep testing if 1 is true. However any professional C programmer should immediately recognize both idioms as both are used.

In terms of actual performance there should be no difference. The compiler will optimize away the test.

I tried testing both to see which is faster but neither of them has completed yet.

Comment: Maybe wait a little longer...?

Comment: Keep an eye on that and let us know.  ;)

Comment: ++ just for the last sentence ;-)

Comment: I suppose semantically `while(true)` is correct, or `for(ever)` if you want to abuse the preprocessor :)

Answer (score 4):

I would argue neither is more optimized, as neither will accomplish the task of looping infinitely in any measurable amount of time.

Is it really possible to reach infinity more or less efficiently?

Comment: True fact: Jon Skeet can execute an infinite loop in three and a half seconds flat.

Comment: @mmyers: I thought that was Chuck Norris?

Comment: ...and by removing a single line of code he can optimize it to run in 0 seconds.

Comment: @Frustrated: Jon Skeet is the new Chuck Norris

Comment: @Frustrated: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts/9199#9199

Comment: It's not possible actually to reach infinity more or less efficiently, but it is possible to go through the motions at a faster or slower rate; 2^n never reaches infinity in the same way that log(n) doesn't either, but my goodness, log(n) will take you a whole whack longer! (Sure, they both tend to infinity as n tends to infinity, but this is where the whole field of analysis comes in; exponents beat powers beat logs etc.)

Answer (score 2):

In theory, a *completely* naive compiler could store the literal '1' in the binary (wasting space) and check to see if 1 == 0 every iteration (wasting time and more space).

In reality, however, even with "no" optimizations, compilers will still reduce both to the same. They may also emit warnings because it could indicate a logical error. For instance, the argument of while could be defined somewhere else and you not realize it's constant.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing. compiler will translate it to a single JMP instruction.

Answer (score 0):

This is my opinion (no research done):

When debugging code as I step through it, for for loops it makes me go to all three parts the first time, then two the rest of the iterations.  However, the while loop only has one.  Just a thought.