# Empty while loop not checking condition

Tags: c++, multithreading, sleep, conditional-statements, while-loop

In a multithreaded C++ program, I have the equivalent of this running in one thread:

```
while(obj->member) { } // waiting for obj->member to be set to false in another thread
```

and in another thread, obj->member is set to false. Even when it's set to false, however, the loop doesn't break. If I change it to this:

```
while(obj->member) { Sleep(1) }
```

It works as expected and breaks when obj->member is set to false in the other thread.
Why does it work like this?

Comment: Please don't use busy wait - learn about condition variables or similar synchronization primitives.

Comment: What? I have no idea what that means.

Comment: I'll second what @Arkadiy said (and if you have no idea what that means, you need to do a lot of reading before you write any more multithreaded code).  In addition to the busy wait (which is merely bad form), your code is also not thread safe.  Given the simplicity of what you're doing _in this exact case_, however, I don't think you'll run into a problem on any common CPU architecture.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try making member `volatile`. This will force it to be fetched from memory each time it is used, rather than from a CPU register (which is how the compiler might optimise it.)

Answer (score 6):

`Obj` must be declared `volatile`.  That tells the compiler that it's value may change by some other thread.

When you add the `Sleep`, the compiler knows other threads are at work, and assumes that it might change.

Comment: The compiler knows that from the `volatile` keyword, not the presence of `Sleep`.

Comment: @CareyGregory Except, apparently, the compiler WAS able to know that from just the `Sleep()`, based on the OP.

Comment: Maybe, but I'm skeptical. There's no reason why the presence of `Sleep` indicates there are other threads in the process. Adding `Sleep` or some other yielding operation inside a tight loop is very common even in single threaded apps. I think it's more likely OP's unyielding loop simply starved the other thread sufficiently that it was never able to set the flag.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that it works is mostly accidental. If you want to do things like this dependably, you just about need to use some sort of OS-supplied IPC mechanism, possibly with [Boost Interprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224138/infinite-loops-top-or-bottom) (e.g., mutex or semaphore) to give a more portable front end.

`volatile`, while often put forward as a solution to problems like this, is neither necessary nor sufficient. It can hurt performance (a lot) but still isn't enough to make threading work correctly. If you're programing for .NET, Microsoft *has* defined its version of `volatile` to provide (at least some degree of) thread safety. Otherwise (in real C or C++), it's of little real use, and can cause considerable harm.

I should also mention that this is a *long* ways from the first time this mistake has been made. Way back when, no less an authority than Andre Alexandrescu wrote a fairly substantial article in Doctor Dobbs about using `volatile` for threading. He's since realized that he was wrong, but (to a large extent) the damage was done -- especially since `volatile` is oh so very close to doing the right things that it's extremely easy to mistake it for being right/useful in threading.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do this would be to use an event instead of the bool.  With an event, you can wait on it without using any CPU, and you will not have to sleep or use volitile.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your threading library is making a copy of the object upon thread creation and the member is not really shared among threads unless it is declared static.