# What's the purpose of "for(;;)"

Tags: c++

In an old codebase, I found the following snippet:

```
for(;;){
  // code that manipulates a vector 'vec'
  if(vec.empty()) break;
}
```

Is there any purpose or convention behind using `for(;;)` instead of `while(true)`, except for personal taste of the respective author?

Comment: And then there's this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224138/infinite-loops-top-or-bottom

Comment: Some people like to do `#define EVER ;;` and then have `for(EVER)` :)

Comment: I remember seeing `while (true)` throwing a warning regarding conditional depending on constant expression (or something similar), while using some compiler, where `for (;;)` wouldn't do that.

Comment: Canonical: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186809/endless-loop-in-c-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Older C++ compilers would not issue a warning for `for(;;)` but they would for `while(true)`. Ditto for C, but with `while(1)`.

Thus the convention stuck.

Comment: Interesting - presumably some "condition always evaluates to true" warning "inherited" from more complex expressions and not given a special case in the way that a totally empty condition (permissible only for a `for`) apparently was.

Comment: I'm not sure what should constitute a bug fix for such a compiler

Comment: This is a good historical perspective. If you add that the statements are semantically equivalent, QoI aside, I'll just delete my answer as redundant

Comment: According to the accepted answer linked by Hans Passant in comments, the reason `for(;;)` is legal code is that the empty second expression is replaced by a nonzero constant. Presumably the compiler that makes that replacement assumes that it is intentional on the part of the programmer, which is why no diagnostic is issued.

Comment: @TimRandall: Methinks it's simpler than that: the "expressions" in the `for` loop (or whatever they are called these days), can be optionally present or absent leading to 8 different possibilities. Deciding on which combinations would yield warnings would have been tedious, particularly in the old days.

Comment: @Bathsheba could be. I can't see a significant difference between these theories, at this point in time.

Answer (score 3):

No.

It is personal taste only.

It is entirely equivalent to a `while (true)`.