# Constant value in conditional expression

Tags: c++, c, warnings, visual-c++

In a [coding style question about infinite loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224138/infinite-loops-top-or-bottom), some people mentioned they prefer the for(;;) style because the while(true) style gives warning messages on MSVC about a conditional expression being constant.

This surprised me greatly, since the use of constant values in conditional expressions is a useful way of avoiding #ifdef hell. For instance, you can have in your header:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_FOO
extern int foo_enabled;
#else
#define foo_enabled 0
#endif
```

And the code can simply use a conditional and trust the compiler to elide the dead code when CONFIG_FOO isn't defined:

```
if (foo_enabled) {
    ...
}
```

Instead of having to test for CONFIG_FOO every time foo_enabled is used:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_FOO
if (foo_enabled) {
    ...
}
#endif
```

This design pattern is used all the time in the Linux kernel (for instance, include/linux/cpumask.h defines several macros to 1 or 0 when SMP is disabled and to a function call when SMP is enabled).

What is the reason for that MSVC warning? Additionally, is there a better way to avoid #ifdef hell without having to disable that warning? Or is it an overly broad warning which should not be enabled in general?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A warning doesn't automatically mean that code is *bad*, just suspicious-looking.

Personally I start from a position of enabling all the warnings I can, then turn off any that prove more annoying than useful. That one that fires anytime you cast anything to a bool is usually the first to go.

Answer (score 5):

I think the reason for the warning is that you might inadvertently have a more complex expression that evaluates to a constant without realizing it. Suppose you have a declaration like this in a header:

```
const int x = 0;
```

then later on, far from the declaration of x, you have a condition like:

```
if (x != 0) ...
```

You might not notice that it's a constant expression.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's to catch things like

```
 if( x=0 )
```

when you meant

```
 if( x==0 )
```

Comment: Good point.  This is one reason one sees "backwards" comparisons like "if (0 == x)" -- if you miss one = sign, the compiler catches it!

Comment: If that's what it wants to catch, couldn't it catch only that (assignment within a conditional) instead of a more general warning?

Comment: That generates a different warning. With VC++ it's: Compiler Warning (level 4) C4706 assignment within conditional expression

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to avoid the warning would be:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_FOO
extern int foo_enabled;
#else
extern int foo_enabled = 0;
#endif
```

Comment: Are you sure you can extern a variable and at the same time give it a value? What if it's initialized to a different value where it's defined? "static const int foo_enabled = 0;" would be a better choice.