# What's the point of issuing a compiler warning for "while(true)" and not issuing one for "for(;;)"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings

When I compile C++ code with Visual C++ 9 with "warning level 4" the following:

```
while( true ) {
   //loop body with break on certain condition
}
```

and the following:

```
for( ; true; ) {
   //same loop body
}
```

both trigger `C4127: conditional expression is constant` warning but the following:

```
for( ; ; ) {
   //same loop body
}
```

compiles without warning.

Why this difference, especially between the second and the third variant?

Comment: because there is no any conditional expression in third statement...while it is there in second and third.... how can compiler generate warning regarding conditional expression without having any?

Comment: I usually end up disabling C4127 with `#pragma warning`, especially when using boost.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224421/constant-value-in-conditional-expression

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is simple, though stupid.

It is important to diagnose infinite loop, but such might not be evident:

```
while(i >= 0) { --i; } // infinite if i unsigned

while(SOME_MACRO(i)) // err, depends on the expansion of macros
```

It is a great feature of a compiler to produce a warning for a tautological test, that is a test that turns out to be either always true or always false, because it's not obvious when it comes from a macro expansion or within a dependent context.

It just seems that VC++ pushed a bit too far here, and instead of considering tautological conditions warns for all `true` or `false` conditions it can find, even when they are already clearly stated in the code.

Answer (score 10):

The reason for warning the user of constant conditional expressions is to help avoid bugs where the expression ends up being constant (for example, due to a typo). In the last case, there is no expression, so there is no risk of it accidentally being constant.

Answer (score 4):

The `for ( ;; )` construct is the canonical way to *intentionally* code an "endless" loop. I could imagine the compiler designers didn't want to generate a warning for that.

Comment: I'd say causation is the other way - it's canonical *because* it doesn't issue a warning on a certain popular compiler series.

Comment: I don't think its even canonical if you include compilers other than VS. I don't think gcc warns on this?

Comment: @jk: You are actually right, GCC does not warn about either of these constructs. I didn't test for this, just speculated.

Answer (score 4):

No point. After all, the langauge specification says ($6.5.3/2),

> Either or both of the condition and
>   the expression can be omitted. **A
>   missing condition makes the implied
>   while clause equivalent to
>   while(true).**

So `for ( ; ; )` is equivalent to `while(true)` even according to the Standard. Therefore, I don't see any reason why the compiler should give warning in one case but not in the other!

--

If the compiler decides to give warning, then in my opinion, the compiler should give warning when the condition is *missing* as opposed to when it's present, so that the warning would be interpreted as *hint* for programmer to mention his  *intention* clearly and *explicitly*.

I mean, `for ( ;; )` is **more likely to be a typo** than the *explicit* mention of condition in `for ( ;true; )`. The latter tells programmer's clear and explicit intent. As **Steve** says in comment:

> For an int value y, char x = y is
>   equivalent to char x = (char)y, but
>   you might want a warning for an
>   implicit narrowing conversion on the
>   first but not the second.

**So explicit intention should not receive warning, while implicit intention should receive!**

Comment: Not my downvote, but I think equivalence is a red herring. For another example, according to the standard `if (x = y)` is equivalent to `if ((x = y))`, but GCC warns for the former and not the latter. For an int value y, `char x = y` is equivalent to `char x = (char)y`, but you might want a warning for an implicit narrowing conversion on the first but not the second.

Comment: true but I find the idea that while(true) is likely to be a typo to be unconvincing. imho VS is overly fussy here

Comment: @jk: I certainly agree that `while(true)` isn't likely to be a typo. In fact I prefer it, so MSVC annoys me. Rather than a typo, it might be the result of a preprocessor expansion `while(CONDITION)`, where CONDITION is accidentally defined to something always true. At least, I always assumed that's what was going through MS's mind when they invented the warning. IMO the warning should only be issued if there's also no `break` in the loop. Or not at all - accidental infinite loops tend not to be the subtlest bugs once you run the code...

Comment: @Steve: I quoted your comment in my post. Hope you don't mind. :-)

Comment: @Steve: undecidable... if you loop is interrupted by an exception, the compiler cannot know that unless it inspects the body of the function calls... which are obviously in another translation unit.

Comment: @Mattheiu: OK, but that's just more reason *not* to warn if the code calls out of the TU. It'd be a much more difficult analysis, though, than to do what MS has done. They've decided that loops which cannot terminate in the loop condition are worthy of a warning, except that they've allowed one particular syntax to suppress the warning. So I have one complaint that the syntax they picked is not my favoured syntax, and a separate second complaint that I think the warning is excessive anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler warning are here to help catch potential bugs. Using an always `true` condition in a `while` loop is probably an error. For exemple, in the following code, this is probably a bug, and I'd like the compiler to warn me about it:

```
unsigned int x;
// ...
while (x >= 0) {
    // ...
}
```

In such a situation, in optimized build the compiler will probably deduce that the condition is always true (since an unsigned integer cannot be smaller than 0). So there is a need for detection of an always `true` condition in `while` loop. I think that whoever wrote the detection of such an error didn't special case the `while (true)` case, as there is a simple way to do a infinite loop with `for (;;)`.

You can read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/03/danger-will-robinson.aspx), how the decision to add a warning or not in Visual Studio, is taken (the exemple are about `C#` but I suppose that the team has the same rule of thumb for warning in `C++`).