# Copy constructor and assignment operator with fundamental types

Tags: c++

I have started to develop with C++ and I have a doubt about copy constructor and assignment operator.

I have this class:

```
class MyTime
{
private:
    unsigned char _hour;
    unsigned char _minute;
    float _second;
    signed char _timeZone;
    unsigned char _daylightSavings;
    double _decimalHour;
public:
    MyTime(unsigned char hour, unsigned char minute, float second, signed char timeZone, unsigned char daylightSavings);
    MyTime(const MyTime& copySource);
    MyTime& operator=(const MyTime& source);
    ~MyTime();

    unsigned char getHour();
    unsigned char getMinute();
    float getSeconds();
    signed char getTimeZone();
    unsigned char getDayLightSavings();
    double getDecimalHour();
};
```

And copy constructor and assignment operator implementation:

```
MyTime::MyTime(const MyTime& copySource)
{
    this->_hour = copySource._hour;
    this->_minute = copySource._minute;
    this->_second = copySource._second;
    this->_timeZone = copySource._timeZone;
    this->_daylightSavings = copySource._daylightSavings;
}

MyTime& MyTime::operator=(const MyTime& source)
{
    this->_hour = source._hour;
    this->_minute = source._minute;
    this->_second = source._second;
    this->_timeZone = source._timeZone;
    this->_daylightSavings = source._daylightSavings;

    return *this;
}
```

Are these implementations required?

I need to make sure that when I assign an instance of MyTime it will create a new instance with its values.

Comment: Your assignment operator will not create a new instance but just overwrite the the values with `source` 's ones. Not sure if that is what you mean

Comment: Oh. I'm new in C++ language. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your copy constructor and assignment operators are just copying the values from `copySource` and `source` respectively into your instance.

You're **not** creating a new instance, just overwriting your instance's values with those of `copySource` and `source`.

As it stands, your class doesn't even require writing copy constructor and assignment operator since the compiler will implicitly generate them for you.
This is a feature of the C++ language, I recommend reading more about this [here: Copy constructors in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) (ndMarco: I understand this might not be the easiest source to learn from, but it is one of the most complete and accurately written available).

Copying each member variable from an instance to another is not a [deep-copy](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/912-shallow-vs-deep-copying/) problem and thus no action is required on your side.

As a follow-up for your studies take a look at the [rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Start with the rule of three (understand why your class doesn't need any of them and what would happen if it needed one of them) and then move on to understanding C++11 concepts.

One last secondary thing: using a verbose `this->member_variable` isn't needed in C++ unless you need to make it clear you're referring to a member variable instead of a local one e.g.

```
class MyClass {
  public:

  int value = 33;

  void function() {
      int value = 42; // Now there's confusion
      std::cout << value; // 42
  }
};
```

so in your case `this->` is not required. Anyway as a style preference you might still use it to make it clear you're referring to a member variable of that class. Just be aware of this small caveat. This is intended as an addition to the fact that you **should not** name your local variables and class members in the same way (that's a terrible practice).

There are still many things that could be added or built over these concepts but they would steer this post off-topic. Just make your mind on these preliminary concepts and you might call it a day.

Comment: re "this->". Yes, but the preferred solution is not to give local variables the same names as class members!

Answer (score 2):

No. Your class as it stands does not require copy constructor, assignment operator or destructor. The compiler-generated ones will do exactly what you require.

Also, from a style POV, you don't need all the "this->" stuff to access class members, unless you're choosing bad names for local variables, or are doing [complex template-related stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577243/is-there-any-reason-to-use-this).

Comment: Haha! Bonus question - "when using this-> qualified notation to access a member is required and the code will not be compiled otherwise? :)".

Comment: @SergeyA. Good question :) I have no idea, but it's probably in some dark corner of the language involving templates.

Comment: @Roddy, you guessed right. There is a really dark magic with two-phases lookup which would require this-> qualification. And since the errors you are gonna get in this case are soooo confusing, some people advocate to start using this-> qualification every time.

Answer (score 1):

No, your code is equivalent to the default copy-constructor and assignment operator. A compiler will generate these as needed. As a rule of thumb, you need to define your own versions if you use dynamic memory or some objects without copy semantics.

As a simple example, if you write `new` in your constructor, you will have to write a matching `delete` in your destructor, and then by the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) you will have to do something with a copy-constructor and an assignment operator. If you avoid managing memory manually, you don't have to worry about these.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine not to do it, as your compiler should generate them for you. However, this is not that case in all classes. A compiler generated copy constructor/assignment operator will basically just use the `=` operator for everything, which is not a good case if you are using pointers and dynamic memory:

Take a string class. You have a `char*` which you reallocate with internal functions inside the string class and assign using functions like `copy`, e.t.c.

However, if a copy construct/assignment operator is omitted for a class like a `string`, the compiler should automatically create one, which unlike what you want, will simply point your pointers to the pointer of the class to be copied from, which will cause large errors, as once that class is modified, your string will also be modified as they both point to the same memory. As a result, for classes that you do not want the compiler to use a simple `operator=` on all the members with, you should define the copy constructor/operator=... otherwise there is no need as long as you have a good compiler

Note: you do not need `this->` to access the members as you are not inheriting them from a templated class.