# Public inheritance of a class template fails unexpectedly

Tags: c++, templates

Why does the following fail with `error: 'a_' was not declared in this scope` in the context of `Bar::get()`?

```
template <typename N>
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo() { }

protected:
  N a_;
};

template <typename N>
class Bar : public Foo<N>
{
public:
  Bar() : Foo<N>() { }

  N get() { return a_; }
};
```

Comment: An answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/577290/2682312).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the reference `this->_a`

`N get() { return this->a_; }`

Comment: You do not _need_ to use `this->`; `Foo<N>::` would also work.