# c++ "this" keyword in operator overloading and without using "this" keyword work same

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

`res.var= this->var+obj.var;`

`res.var = var + obj.var;`

both work same so what the benefit of using **this** keyword
Here is my code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class MyClass {
 public:
  int var, v;
  MyClass() {}
  MyClass(int a, int b) 
  : var(a), v(b) { }
  MyClass operator+(MyClass &obj) {
   MyClass res;
   res.var = this->var + obj.var;
   res.v = v + obj.v;
   return res; 
  }
};

int main(){
    MyClass ob(12, 12);
    MyClass ob1(55, 56);
    MyClass res = ob + ob1;
    cout << res.var << " " << res.v;
}
```

can anyone explain me the benefit of this keyword in operator overloading

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any reason to use this->](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577243/is-there-any-reason-to-use-this) or [When should I make explicit use of the `this` pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993352/when-should-i-make-explicit-use-of-the-this-pointer)

Answer (score 2):

It's there for clarity: it has absolutely no effect on the generated program.

Some folk prefer `(*this).` for even better symmetry.

Occasionally you do need to use `this` to disambiguate from a local variable or even another token; the latter can occur when working with templates and some compilers don't follow the rules properly.

Note that you should pass `const MyClass& obj` else anonymous temporaries can't bind to your overloaded function: an expression like `ob1 + ob2 + ob3` would not compile as you have it.