# Variable Naming Conventions in Programming

Tags: naming-conventions

On a lot of occasion when looking at codes for embedded systems or linux kernels, I would come accross variables being named in a following manner:

```
var_u16;
```

For example suffix _u8 (unsigned 8-bit integer), _au16 (array of unsigned 16-bit integers), _pfu (pointer to function), etc. is added.

What is the naming of this convention?

I am looking for the documentation to see the rules of this type of naming convention and my searches to find it are coming empty. In my opinion this seems like a more understandable approach to Hungarian notation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The opposite of Hungarian Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610157/the-opposite-of-hungarian-notation)