# "Each namespace should exist within its own assembly" Please explain

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been given some criteria for a project.  It MUST be constructed in a particular way.  I know this isn't a great question but my C# is really rusty.  The specification states:

> Application namespaces should follow (but not be limited to) the below
>   [actual names changed]:

```
AnExample.Sample.Foo
AnExample.Sample.Foo.UnitTests
AnExample.Sample.Bar
AnExample.Sample.Bar.UnitTests
```

and that `"each namespace should exist within its own assembly"`.

I'm a little confused- what is being asked for and how to achieve it?  For each namespace to exist in it's "own assembly" does it have to be a separate project and referenced or is it a folder structure?

Comment: Each project is compiled to one assembly (DLL or EXE file)

Comment: might be applicable for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218123/what-was-the-strangest-coding-standard-rule-that-you-were-forced-to-follow :)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: SLaks said it. Each C# project (`.csproj` file) is compiled in one "go" and becomes one [assembly (follow link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3677y81.aspx). An assembly is often a `.dll` or `.exe` file, possibly with other related files, like a `.pdb`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

each namespace would have to be in its own project (.csproj)

within your projects, you could have whatever folder structure you wanted, as along as the namespace in the entire project is the same.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: I think it is a legal answer.

Comment: I think it is too short to be one.#

Comment: i could prop it up with more fluff, but unless the CrimsonChin needs some extra detail, im not sure what else to put here.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what they're asking you for is that each namespace is in its own separate file.

A project compiles to an assembly, which can be a .dll or an .exe. What they're saying is that each separate namespace should be in a separate project, so it compiles to a separate file. This is good for decoupling. You can then bring them all together using the <kbd>Add Reference...</kbd> button in VS.

Comment: More words, but less total semantic content. I vote for Kevin's answer.