# How to calculate "views"?

Tags: web-applications, view, count

What is a reasonable, efficient, and fair method to calculate page views?

For example, how does Stack Overflow compute question views?  I thought that Stack Overflow computes views per registered user. However, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered) has 198,000 views and there are 56,000 registered users in Stack Overflow (go to users page, 1604 pages, 35 users per page).

Comment: I've refreshed this page a few times and it hasn't increased the view count, so there's at least some merging of repeat views by the same user, although I suspect it's within a set time period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a black-box approach, I'd imagine that it is a similar approach to things like Flickr, which would count a view as a request per session (which would inherently be "per user" as well), but ignore views by the content creator.

Answer (score 0):

Page views mean how many times a page is viewed by a user. Based on your statistics sfo seem to use this logic.

Page views by unique user will be based on registered user. If a registered user have seen a page then viewing the page again will not increment the count.

Depends what logic you want to use.