# have comments any influence on script in php?

Tags: php

is it possible, that in php something, which was written as comment( like `//comment...`), makes some influence on the script? i remember, that once i use open source script, but when i delete all comments from it, it became non working. sorry for an abstract question. i haven't the code now, so i dont show it.

Comment: // sometimes I believe compiler ignores all my comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered/185803#185803

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments should not affect code in anyway, provided:

- The script is not opening itself/another file of code through a `fread` or similar function, and searching for data in the comments.

However, if you removed comments that were commenting out lines of code that are now not commented out, there would be a problem.