# PHP define() function

Tags: php, c++, debugging

Is there any possible way to get this working:

[What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered/771974#771974) (which I think is C++, but I have no idea)

...working in PHP?  I'd love to mess with my co-workers as a little prank and see what happens ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[No. There's not.](http://www.ideone.com/7oOf8)

PHP doesn't have a preprocessor (strictly speaking, it *is* the preprocessor!); within its scope, keywords trump constants.

A C++ "trick" like this:

```
#define true false
```

works because the preprocessor manipulates the code on a context-less basis... though it should be noted that the standard makes that "trick" illegal (strictly speaking, "undefined").

The scenario is a little different in C, but the general principle isn't much different.

Comment: Not this specific trick - `TRUE` is not a language keyword or existing specifier, it's just a macro.

Comment: @DeadMG: Er yes, sorry, `s/C/C++/` and lowercase. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Even though you will not get an error message for this since `define` does not check the list of reserved words, it will not work. Boolean values are globally defined in PHP.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php and http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=13505 for more infos.