# Handling multiple string using REGEX in java

Tags: java, junit

I have 5 strings "a,b,c,d,e" in a drop down,i am writing a testcase where i am checking if the user has selected any of the five then insert into DB,currently i am not getting any of the values from client side,so it has to be written in a junit if the user has selected any of these values then return true .

current approach:
1st method having 'a' data
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
obj.put("DT",a);

2nd method having 'b' data
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
obj.put("DT",b);

and so on for furthur values.which is creating more number of methods.I need to insert all the values in a single method.

Thanks

Comment: How does regex come into play here?

Comment: And who thought this was a clear question???

Comment: @Peter: the person who asked the question.

Comment: @Kowser, indeed, but he can't be the upvoter...

Comment: @Peter: I think it is a god. Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered/316233#316233

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused as to what you're actually struggling with.  Are you just looking for a helper method to do this?

```
public static JSONObject createAndPopulateObject(String data) {
  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
  obj.put("DT", data);
  return obj;
}

//...
aObj = createAndPopulateObject("a");
bObj = createAndPopulateObject("b");
```