# Should you change your controller class to have .mm extension if interoperating with C++ code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c++

When interoperating with C++ code, should you create your ViewController as a .mm file or should you instead setup a facade between your controller and the C++ class?

What are the downsides of making a ViewController class become Objective-C++?

Comment: You mean as a style question? You _can_ do either of those things.

Comment: No - in terms of performance and compiler issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to use the C++ code from different places (say, different view controllers), it may pay off to make a wrapper class to have everything encapsulated nicely. That way you'll only have one `.mm` file instead of several of them.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8056515/269753) contends that .mm files take more time to compile. Check it out for additional information on *Objective-C++*.

In any case, I'd try to keep ObjC and C++ as isolated as possible, if only for increased maintainability and simplicity.

Comment: Agreed, with an extra reason that refactoring tools are basically broken for .mm files.

Comment: Good point, I almost forgot about that. Such an annoyance. I have AppCode installed just to refactor *C++* and *ObjC++* code.