# Convert psd to png giving via imagemagick giving garbage output

Tags: imagemagick, psd, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to run convert over a psd to create a png per layer. Running

```
$ convert psdname.psd output.png
```

creates the right number of pngs, but the content is totally garbled - like horizontal lines running across the screen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuQc7.jpg

I thought it might be a colorspace issue (the psd is in CMYK) but adding -colorspace doesn't do anything. I'm totally at a loss

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to provide a demo PSD that causes these problems. Plus version information about your ImageMagick and Photoshop.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/769443/517371 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately PSD support in open source software has been marginal at best. [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) can handle PSD files with layers pretty well, it can't work with nested layers though. You still might want to take a look at it since it's highly scriptable and may work for you.