# File not opening in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, inputstream

Im trying to read a simple text file with contents
**input.txt**

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

But it always goes to the exception and prints Error.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        List<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
            for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
                 text.add(line);
            }
            System.out.println(text.size()); //print how many lines read in
            reader.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
    }   
}
```

Im using Eclipse as my IDE if that makes a difference. I've tried this code on http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php
and it runs fine, why wont it run in Eclipse?

Comment: Try printing out the exception. Then you'll know what the error actually is.

Comment: I'm guessing `FileNotFoundException` - but yes, you should never ignore the exception itself.

Comment: Agreed. Likely input.txt isn't in the correct folder.

Comment: If you dont understand others comments then they mean to use `catch{e.printStackTrace()....}`

Comment: The full error is file not found,

Comment: Actually,`SOP("ERROR")` went me directly to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered/549611#549611) :)

Comment: changing the "input.txt" to "src\\input.txt" fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

give complete file path like `"C:\\folder_name\\input.txt"` or place input.txt inside src directory of eclipse project.

Comment: its inside the src folder already, ill try using the full file path

Comment: full path not required if txt file is inside src(classpath). Try printing out the exception using e.printStackTrace();

Comment: It says the system cannot find the file specified

Comment: the full path works, but i would rather have a way to refer to the current directory

Comment: **NOTE:** use `slash(/)` instead `backslash(\\)` because of different platforms.

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: Use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to get running directory.
Also, use `java.io.File.separator` instead of `\\` or  `/` to be platform-independent:

`System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+"input.txt"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        List<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader("input.txt"));  //<< your problem is probably here, 
            //More than likely you have to supply a path the input file.
            //Something like "C:\\mydir\\input.txt"
            for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
                 text.add(line);
            }
            System.out.println(text.size()); //print how many lines read in
            reader.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("ERROR"); //This tells you nothing.
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());  //Do this
            //or 
            e.printStackTrace(); //this or both

        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: is there a way I can refer to the current directory?

Comment: What you are doing does refer to the current directory, but I _suspect_ that is your problem.  Until you have the stack trace you don't really know.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have a bad path.  Consider this main instead:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        List<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
             text.add(line);
        }
        System.out.println(text.size()); //print how many lines read in
        reader.close();
    }   
}
```

The "throws Exception" addition allows you to focus on the code, and consider better error handling later.  Also consider using `File f = new File("input.txt")` and use that, because it allows you to print out `f.getAbsolutePath()` which tells you the filename it was actually looking for.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile. `public class Main throws Exception {` is wrong, maybe you were talking about `public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {`?

Answer (score 0):

Changing `input.txt` to `src\\input.txt` solved the problem!
I guess it was because the current directory isnt actually the src folder its the parent,

Thanks for the help!

Comment: When you just say `input.txt` then it will start looking in its root folder (where your src and other project related folder resides ), that means your project folder. When you say `src\\input.txt` that means `root folder\src\input.txt`.