# On hover display menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am wondering if there's a tutorial to display a context-like menu 
when hovering a button, this is very similar to Google Plus onHover 
menu effect seen below:

[image]

Any tutorial on this is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I was thinking of a way to display it when hovering, like the usage of an "open" to "toggle" class, but not sure, any help or tutorial on this is appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: [Type of Questions to Avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @NathanLee do you know of any way to achieve this result? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Is your Google search broken? There are dozens of links you could follow instead of asking someone else to do the work for you, right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're trying to get us to do your work for you here...because you've obviously not even gone to google

Comment: LOL, I have Googled this for over a week now, and no result

Comment: You are proably not using the right keywords. Regardless, this doesn't look diffcult to achieve and im sure there are thousands on ppl on SO who can answer this in 5 mins completely to the detail. But every1 would like to see you make an effort

Comment: You could take a look at how Bootstrap does it, http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns - Basically you'd have a `container element` with a `trigger` and a `menu` inside. When the trigger is clicked/hovered, the menu appears.

Comment: @M_Willett  thanks for you effort, but bootstrap is nothing I want to follow. If there's a better way to do this practically, I'd be happy to see the solutions or the tutorial on it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the very good method used in Bootstrap (this is how I'd do it):

Have a container, a trigger and a menu.

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown_container">

    <a class="dropdown_trigger">Button</a>

    <ul class="dropdown_menu">
        <li><a>...</a></li>
        <li><a>...</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown_container { position: relative; }
.dropdown_trigger { display: block; }
.dropdown_menu { position:aboslute; top: 100%; display: none; }
.show_dropdown .dropdown_menu { display: block; }
```

**JS**

```
// On click
$('.dropdown_trigger').click( function() {
    $(".dropdown_menu").addClass("show_dropdown");
});

// On hover
$('.dropdown_trigger').hover( function() {
    $(".dropdown_menu").addClass("show_dropdown");
});

// Or add the css directly
$('.dropdown_trigger').hover( function() {
    $(".dropdown_menu").css("display", "block");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You might find the below link helpful:

http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/trigger-hover-autohide.html

Comment: This is very close to what I was looking for, is there a way to achieve this with pure CSS 2.0?

Comment: You mean without any javascript or jquery?

Comment: @sr. Yes if possible, not sure if G+ uses jQuery or if they achieved this with pure CSS.

Comment: @JohnSmith, almost every website you see now uses jQuery.

Comment: The menu is drawn by the PHP when the page is generated, but it will remain hidden until Hover of course.

Comment: @MarsOne sure, but what about backward-compatibility with older browsers?

Comment: @john With CSS3 that could be done I think. With CSS2 I am not sure.

Comment: Which older browsers are you talking about , IE6, IE7? jQuery 1.X is supported in ie6+, jquery 2.X is supported in ie9+. I think ie8 is almost dead now and dont even bother with 6 & 7

Comment: @JohnSmith cleanest way will be to build and hide your HTML menu on your page, and show it using javascript on hover. That is all it takes. Easy :) What you want is a clean and nice looking menu like Google's. Showing and hiding is easy. But that sample I provided is also cool, and easy. You could still try that.

Comment: Reagrding the code, the code is clean and minimal. Hardly 12 lines of it.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered/184673#184673 for hilarious code

Comment: @MarsOne LOL! LOL! LOL! LOL!

Answer (score 1):

The best way in my opinion is using pure css

**CSS:**

```
.button {
    position: relative;
}

    .button .hovermenu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 25px;
        left: 0px;
        display: none;
    }

    .button:hover .hovermenu {
        display: block;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="button">
        This has a hovermenu!
        <div class="hovermenu">
            <ul>
                <li>Submenu item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The advantage of this is that you can add as much buttons with a submenu as you like (`<li></li>`), and you only have to set the `top` and `left` right to position them all correctly relative to their parent menu item

Comment: provide a fiddle sample plz! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JohnSmith http://jsfiddle.net/Tumtum/gF7eh/

Answer (score 1):

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=css+drop+down+menu+tutorial&aq=2&oq=css+drop+downs&aqs=chrome.3.57j0l3j62l2.4118j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

This will give hundreds of tutorials about what you want,

you can create such a menu with simple css only, have a look here,

http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

ok you've got two event optins here, here's the OBVIOUS one;

```
$( "img" ).hover(
  function() {
    showMenu(); //hyperthetical function to show whatever
  }, function() {
     hideMenu();//hyperthetical function to show whatever
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a tutorial to do that. It's simple css.

```
//Your button
<input type="button" class="btn" />

//Your div that contains the contextual-like menu
<div class="contextualMenu">
   your contextual menu goes here
</div>

//And the css code is (menu is hidden by default and shows up only when you hover the button)
.contextualMenu{display:none;}
.btn:hover .contextualMenu{display:block;}
```

Hope this is useful for you.
Cheers!