# Can comments make any difference during the run-time?

Tags: java, c++, c, comments, java-3d

Reading [What is the best comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered) I've encouter [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered#comment-431921) comment, upvoted 201 times:

> A long time ago, I accidentally fixed a segfault in Java3D by adding a
>   comment. It was 100% reproducible; if I removed the comment, it
>   crashed. As long as the comment was there, it worked fine. I assume it
>   was some bizarre timing issue, but I never did figure out exactly what
>   was happening.

Is this possible?

If he was fixing a segfault in Java3D, I'm guessing he was writing code in Java or C/C++. I thought that in  any of these languages, comments are simply erased before the compilation...

Comment: it is not possible, what would happen is there was a special character in the position where he inserted the comment, it happened to me before also, things of working on unix,windows and solaris for same code.

Comment: In C and C++ the comments are removed by the pre-processor: even before the compiler sees the code.  I have seen comments give a warning, for example: `// does this work???` used to give a warning about an invalid trigraph.

Comment: @RamonBoza That's interesting about this special character (which one?) - could you please elaborate in the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that in any of these languages, comments are simply erased
>   before the compilation...

It might seem so but, unfortunately, this *harmless*-looking `Hello World` program wouldn't even compile.

Why?  Because of a **comment**.  The culprit is the path the *source*.  Specifically, `\users`.  The backslash `\` is followed by the letter `u`, denotes the start of a Unicode escape.  The trailing `sers` makes it a ill-formed Unicode escape.  (It would have been ok if `\u` was followed by 4 hex digits -- yes, you need that even in a comment.)

As such, the code wouldn't even compile **due to the comment**.

```
public class HelloWorld {

    /**
     * Source: C:\users\devnull\HelloWorld.java
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you state, in Java comments are not included in the compiled bytecode. For eaxmple, take the following class:

```
public class test {

    public void methodWithoutComment() {
        System.out.println("This method does not have a comment");
    }

    public void methodWithComment() {
        // Method with comment
        System.out.println("This method has a comment");
    }
}
```

If we introspect the byte code with `javap`, using `javap -c test`, we can see the bytecode for both methods are identical - with the exception of the string that is outputted to the console:

```
public class test {
  public test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public void methodWithoutComment();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field     java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #3                  // String This method does not have a comment
       5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: return

  public void methodWithComment();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #5                  // String This method has a comment
       5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't think so. In order to run Java program, it should be compiled into bytecode so comments will be erased during the compilation and can't impact execution of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two explanations for this.

One, the reporter was wrong. They were not making the edit they believed they were making or were compiling or executing incorrectly or the error was erratic and coincided with their edits by chance, *et cetera*.

Two, the edit removed what looked like a comment, but it actually interacted with other syntax. E.g., consider:

```
/* Start comment.
…
/* Not a new comment. */
… Some code here …
/* Sometimes a comment. */
```

When the “Not a new comment” line is present, “Some code here” is source code that is not part of a comment. When the “Not a new comment” line is not present, “Some code here” is part of a comment.