# What are the ways to build an app for Salesforce?

Tags: asp.net, api, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I am looking to implement some customization, calculation, at custom page. And Yes I am new to Sales force , very new.

So I need to know that what are the ways to build an App for SF? ( My custom App will be in AP.NET language)

Also what are the ways to design custom page & internal implementation  at Salesforce?

My requirement : Need one custom page, there will be one form & fields where one user will add some info , no of hours for the task etc... and some calculations I need to do at their local while some may be done at custom App, also I need to send the data on submit/save the form.

So what is the best way?

I have made one simple App using ASP.NET web services through generating WSDL & used the service classes I am able to get data
But still not sure what need to be done after this???
I know its vast question but I need some summarized steps from where I can get to know the steps & other info that I should know but need to develop it fast , as always !!

Thanks in advance All Tech Leads...

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: I have made one simple App using ASP.NET web services through generating WSDL & used the service classes I am able to get data
But still not sure what need to be done after this???

Comment: Yes.. code ? This is a site for solving specific coding issues, not for "how do I do (..)" general solution architecture questions. Sorry..

Comment: ok I am not sure if it is. But thanks for letting me know. But I am desperately need to know the things , so for me its more important then coding issue... And if I want to know solution for my requirement then where can I ask this?? Any suggestion please?

Comment: @sh1rts This question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered

Is this any coding issue??? which gain lots of hits... SOrry I am not here to prove anybody right or wrong but for getting my solution of the problem. And respect the community of tech experts, really appreciate all of your efforts at here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two general approaches for integrating an ASP.NET app with Salesforce.

1. Create a [Canvas App](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connect/index_Left.htm) in Salesforce that will surface your ASP.NET site in an iframe. Salesforce will POST a signed request to your ASP.NET site that you can use to verify the request came from Salesforce and get a valid Session ID for making calls back into Salesforce via the API.
2. Create a [Composite App](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Single_Sign_On_for_Composite_Apps). This is the older version of a Canvas App. Again, your ASP.NET site will appear in an iframe. Here the Salesforce SessionId and orginating Server URL are passed on the query string.

I'd say go with the Canvas App. You can easily play this within a Visualforce page as required.

Incidentally, there is a dedicated StackExchange site for Salesforce questions at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @ Daniel Ballinger , Wow, that's great help Man ! Thanks