# More than 2 variables in std::pair

Tags: c++

`pair` looks like this:

```
std::vector<std::pair<uint64 /*id*/, std::string /*message*/>
```

And if I want 3 variables in `vector`? Can I use pair or what?

Comment: Use `std::tuple`

Comment: Consider using a struct. That way members will have meaningful names.

Comment: What prevented you from simply reading through your C++ standard library reference to find a suitable tool???

Comment: What?  Why read through boring library docs when some sucker on SO will do the work for you for free?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood correctly you could use `std::tuple` declared in header `<tuple>`. For example

```
std::vector<std::tuple<uint64, std::string, SomeOtherType>> v;
```

Answer (score 5):

In C++ sometimes I find quite useful to define trivial all-public data-only classes like

```
struct Event {
    int id = 0;
    std::string msg = "";
    double time = 0.;
};
```

Surely a bit of typing, but IMO way better than having to use `e.second` or `std::get<1>(e)` instead of `e.msg` everywhere in the code.

Writing is done once, reading many times. Saving writing time at the expense of increasing reading/understanding time is a Very Bad Idea.

The drawback of this approach is that you cannot access the n-th member of the structure in metaprograms, but C++ metaprogramming is terribly weak anyway for a lot of other reasons so if you really need to have non-trivial metacode I'd suggest moving out of C++ and using an external C++ code generator written in a decent language instead of template tricks and hacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want C++11, you can use

```
std::pair<uint64, std::pair<std::string, SomeOtherType> >
```

But this is as wrong as trying to put three values to a *pair*. Why I consider it wrong? A *pair* means *two* values. If you put *three* or any other number of values in a *pair*, you are doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/771974/446252).