# Using arrays in std::pair to extend the amount of data

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdmap, std-pair

I'm trying to extend someone else's code which is using std::queue and std::pair types pretty frequently. For the following code, I need to extend the number of variables in std::pair.second and prefer it to be more flexible for number of variables like an array (for future modification).

```
someClass->myQueue.push(std::pair<T1,uint64_t>(var1, var2));
```

So I tried to do something like:

```
someClass->myQueue.push(std::pair<T1,uint64_t[N]>(var1,{e1,e2,...,eN}));
```

After modifying the related definitions etc. in the code I got following error and warning, which I don't understand anything from. However it sounds like that this is not the appropriate way to do this kind of modification.

```
myArray = myQueue.front().second; 
        ^
error: invalid array assignment
...
someClass->myQueue.push(std::pair<T1,uint64_t[N]>(var1,{e1,e2,...,eN}));
                                                                    ^
warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
```

I saw [tuple and recursive usage of std::pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27593856/more-than-2-variables-in-stdpair) as solutions on web, but I want to make minimum change on the code since several classes will be effected by this. What is the proper way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: `std::pair<T1,std::vector<uint64_t>>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Raw C++ arrays are not copy-assignable. That's the error you're getting. Instead, you should use an array type that *is* copy-assignable: [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Specifically in this case:

```
std::pair<T1, std::array<uint64_t, N>>
```