# Java 8 Streams modify collection values

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Using the stream API; once the relevant data has been filtered I'd like to edit the data being collected. Here is the code so far:

```
  String wordUp = word.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
  String wordDown = word.toLowerCase();

  ArrayList<String> text = Files.lines(path)
        .parallel() // Perform filtering in parallel
        .filter(s -> s.contains(wordUp) || s.contains(wordDown) &&  Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")).contains(word))
        .sequential()
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

**Edit** The code below is awful and I am trying to avoid it.(It also does not entirely work. It was done at 4am, please excuse it.)

```
    for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++) {
        String set = "";
        List temp = Arrays.asList(text.get(i).split(" "));
        int wordPos = temp.indexOf(word);

        List<String> com1 = (wordPos >= limit) ? temp.subList(wordPos - limit, wordPos) : new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> com2 = (wordPos + limit < text.get(i).length() -1) ? temp.subList(wordPos + 1, wordPos + limit) : new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String s: com1)
            set += s + " ";
        for (String s: com2)
            set += s + " ";
        text.set(i, set);
    }
```

It's looking for a particular word in a text file, once the line has been filtered in I'd like to only collect a portion of the line every time. A number of words on either side of the keyword that is being searched for.

eg:

`keyword = "the"`
`limit = 1`

It would find: `"Early in the morning a cow jumped over a fence."`

It should then return: `"in the morning"`

*P.S. Any suggested speed improvements will be up-voted.

Comment: I don't see how you use this `limit` in your code...

Comment: To modify elements, use [map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method of the stream.

Comment: And also, what should happen if the `keyword` is the first in the sentence and `limit` is `1`?

Comment: What's the difference between `wordUp`, `wordDown` and `word`?

Comment: Has the `limit` something to do with the fact that you want to return one word before and after the keyword? i can see no other potential use...

Comment: @kocko the code should do a boundary check then take as many on either side as possible. I will edit the code to show how the limit is used, however just bare-in-mind this was done at 4am and is terrible.
I know this is not the best solution, as I am new to this. (That's why I'm here ^^,)

Comment: @WojciechFrącz - Thank you, I'll have a look at the map function.

Comment: There is no sense in calling `.parallel()` and `.sequential()` on the same stream. A stream is either parallel or sequential. Note that `collect` works flawlessly with parallel streams. Further, your condition `x || y && z` looks suspicious; mind the operator precedence. But it’s not clear what it is supposed to do anyway.

Comment: Coding at 4am? Not too bad. At least you weren't drunk: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered/185181#185181

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two different tasks you should think about. First, convert a file into a list of words:

```
List<String> words = Files.lines(path)
    .flatMap(Pattern.compile(" ")::splitAsStream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This uses your initial idea of splitting at space characters. This might be sufficient for simple tasks, however, you should study [the documentation of `BreakIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html#word) to understand the difference between this simple approach and a real, sophisticated word boundary splitting.

Second, if you have a list of words, your task is to find matches of your `word` and convert sequences of items around the match into a single match `String` by joining the words using a single space character as delimiter:

```
List<String> matches=IntStream.range(0, words.size())
    // find matches
    .filter(ix->words.get(ix).matches(word))
    // create subLists around the matches
    .mapToObj(ix->words.subList(Math.max(0, ix-1), Math.min(ix+2, words.size())))
    // reconvert lists into phrases (join with a single space
    .map(list->String.join(" ", list))
    // collect into a list of matches; here, you can use a different
    // terminal operation, like forEach(System.out::println), as well
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: this answer is fantastic, it is elegant and exactly the sort of answer I am looking for thank you so much. I like that it avoids any issues that might arise when selecting words by line. I will have a look at the link you suggested. One more thing, do you maybe have a link or advice as to how I could find the time complexity of something like this?

Comment: I could be wrong but I assume the time complexity for both is `O(n)` since they go though all `n` elements in the stream. However, together would they be `O(n) + O(n) = O(2n)`?

Comment: @Warosaurus Technically, `O(2n) = O(n)` ;-)