# C++ initializer list with complicated structures

Tags: c++, c, structure, initializer-list

I am working on modifying this C code to work with G++ compiler and I am stuck on this pretty complicated structure. G++ compiler complains "sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported". I know a solution which involves writing a constructor but the call to the constructor will be huge and way too confusing.Is there some way to simplify this and refractor it so that it is more readable and g++ compliant.

```
static const struct {
struct {
    __le32 magic;
    __le32 length;
#ifndef USE_DEPRECATED_DESC_HEAD
    __le32 flags;
#endif
    __le32 fs_count;
    __le32 hs_count;
} __attribute__((packed)) header;
struct {
    struct usb_interface_descriptor intf;
    struct usb_endpoint_descriptor_no_audio svc_in;
    struct usb_endpoint_descriptor_no_audio to_ap;
    struct usb_endpoint_descriptor_no_audio from_ap;
} __attribute__((packed)) fs_descs, hs_descs;
} __attribute__((packed)) descriptors = {
    .header = {
#ifdef USE_DEPRECATED_DESC_HEAD
    .magic = htole32(FUNCTIONFS_DESCRIPTORS_MAGIC),
#else
    .magic = htole32(FUNCTIONFS_DESCRIPTORS_MAGIC_V2),
    .flags = htole32(FUNCTIONFS_HAS_FS_DESC |
                 FUNCTIONFS_HAS_HS_DESC),
#endif
    .length = htole32(sizeof descriptors),
    .fs_count = htole32(4),
    .hs_count = htole32(4),
},
.fs_descs = {
    .intf = {
        .bLength = sizeof descriptors.fs_descs.intf,
        .bDescriptorType = USB_DT_INTERFACE,
        .bNumEndpoints = 3,
        .bInterfaceClass = USB_CLASS_VENDOR_SPEC,
        .iInterface = 1,
    },
    .svc_in = {
        .bLength = sizeof descriptors.fs_descs.svc_in,
        .bDescriptorType = USB_DT_ENDPOINT,
        .bEndpointAddress = 1 | USB_DIR_IN,
        .bmAttributes = USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_INT,
        .bInterval = 10,
        .wMaxPacketSize = 64
    },
    .to_ap = {
        .bLength = sizeof descriptors.fs_descs.to_ap,
        .bDescriptorType = USB_DT_ENDPOINT,
        .bEndpointAddress = 2 | USB_DIR_IN,
        .bmAttributes = USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK,
        .wMaxPacketSize = 64
    },
    .from_ap = {
        .bLength = sizeof descriptors.fs_descs.from_ap,
        .bDescriptorType = USB_DT_ENDPOINT,
        .bEndpointAddress = 3 | USB_DIR_OUT,
        .bmAttributes = USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK,
        .wMaxPacketSize = 64
    },
},
.hs_descs = {
    .intf = {
        .bLength = sizeof descriptors.hs_descs.intf,
        .bDescriptorType = USB_DT_INTERFACE,
        .bNumEndpoints = 3,
        .bInterfaceClass = USB_CLASS_VENDOR_SPEC,
        .iInterface = 1,
    },
    .svc_in = {
        .bLength = sizeof descriptors.hs_descs.svc_in,
        .bDescriptorType = USB_DT_ENDPOINT,
        .bEndpointAddress = 1 | USB_DIR_IN,
        .bmAttributes = USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_INT,
        .bInterval = 10,
        .wMaxPacketSize = 512,
    },
    .to_ap = {
        .bLength = sizeof descriptors.hs_descs.to_ap,
        .bDescriptorType = USB_DT_ENDPOINT,
        .bEndpointAddress = 2 | USB_DIR_IN,
        .bmAttributes = USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK,
        .wMaxPacketSize = 512,
    },
    .from_ap = {
        .bLength = sizeof descriptors.hs_descs.from_ap,
        .bDescriptorType = USB_DT_ENDPOINT,
        .bEndpointAddress = 3 | USB_DIR_OUT,
        .bmAttributes = USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK,
        .wMaxPacketSize = 512,
    },
},
};
```

Comment: C++ doesn't have designated initializers.

Comment: I know that, but how do I initialize without making  huge call to the constructor.

Comment: @ArulMoondra make it a pointer and use `malloc()` instead of `new`? Why would you want that?

Comment: Anyone that has a variable named `magic` is about to cause some trouble... http://stackoverflow.com/a/185106/2296458

Comment: do you reference this structure from any actual c++ code? If not, rename the source file that defines it to .c

Comment: @iharob I didnot understand your comment I was thinking on these lines
typedef struct Foos {
    int a;
    int b;
    Foos(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
};
Which you would initalize like so:

static const struct Foos foo(1, 2);

Comment: @ArulMoondra, can you reduce it to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static const struct {
    struct {
        __le32 magic;
        __le32 length;
#ifndef USE_DEPRECATED_DESC_HEAD
        __le32 flags;
#endif
        __le32 fs_count;
        __le32 hs_count;
    } __attribute__((packed)) header;

    struct {
        struct usb_interface_descriptor intf;
        struct usb_endpoint_descriptor_no_audio svc_in;
        struct usb_endpoint_descriptor_no_audio to_ap;
        struct usb_endpoint_descriptor_no_audio from_ap;
    } __attribute__((packed)) fs_descs, hs_descs;
} __attribute__((packed))
descriptors =
{
    // header
    {
        // magic
#ifdef USE_DEPRECATED_DESC_HEAD
        htole32(FUNCTIONFS_DESCRIPTORS_MAGIC),
#else
        htole32(FUNCTIONFS_DESCRIPTORS_MAGIC_V2),
#endif
        // length
        htole32(sizeof descriptors),

        // flags
#ifdef USE_DEPRECATED_DESC_HEAD
        htole32(FUNCTIONFS_HAS_FS_DESC |
                         FUNCTIONFS_HAS_HS_DESC),
#endif
        // fs_count
        htole32(4),
        htole32(4),
    },
    // fs_descs
    {
        // intf
        {
            sizeof descriptors.fs_descs.intf, // bLength
            USB_DT_INTERFACE, // bDescriptorType
            3, // bNumEndpoints
            USB_CLASS_VENDOR_SPEC,// bInterfaceClass
            1, // iInterface
        },
        // svc_in ...
        // and so on...
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, a question though, I have to keep in mind that the order of the actual structure is preserved. Some of these structures do not initialize a single variable inside out of say 10  but initialize all others. Is there a way of skipping variables in it.

Comment: a skipped variable needs to be a zero i'm afraid