# Sonar complains about Spring Boot configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, sonarqube, spring-cloud, spring-java-config

I have this class to start up the spring-cloud config server.  It is a spring-boot application.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        SpringApplication.run( ConfigServerApplication.class, args );

    }

}
```

The application runs fine and all my unit tests are fine.  However, in our bamboo pipeline, it will initial a sonar process to analyze the code.  We keep getting these minor warnings indicating the following:

```
Utility classes should not have a public constructor
```

I know that this is a minor issue, but I have been tasked with removing these from our code.

Ideally, you would mark the class final and provide a private constructor, or so all searches provide as a solution.  However, a Spring Configuration class cannot be made final and cannot have a private constructor.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't a problem spring-boot or spring-cloud can solve. You need to add exceptions to your sonar configuration.

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb That is what I was thinking as well.  However, I would think sonar would see that that class contains a public static main method and use that as an exception to that rule.

Comment: P.S. Good to meet you at SpringOne2gx. Enjoyed your talks.

Comment: Thanks! nice to meed you too.

Comment: @dmfrey you can actually report that usecase at sonarqube@googlegroups.com so SonarQube team can actually add the exception to this rule ! it's open source, only price is reporting issues :)

Comment: @benzonico I have posted a message to the list. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I saw that, I'll try to reply to it soon ;)

Comment: Hi, can you add an link to the post or to an issue in an issue-tracking-system?

Comment: Any recommendation on how to disable this rule for only the SpringBoot Application and not all public constructors violations?

Comment: It is testable, have a look for my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45374995/863403

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting your sonar settings would be a nicer approach of course, but if you want to [please the machine spirits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/769083/821786), you can simply add a non-static dummy function to your class, making it "non-utility" in the eyes of the Sonar checker.

Comment: This is really hacking around, please report issue to improve the rule and mark it as false positive in your sonarqube instance.

Comment: @benzonico I wasn't going to implement it, but it was just funny that it came up multiple times.

Comment: I assume it was a bit personal for him as he is working on Sonar. If you would happen to report it, would you mind leaving a link to the Jira ticket here? I wonder how long will it take to get it fixed.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy to test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class YourApplicationTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldLoadApplicationContext() {
    }

    @Test
    public void applicationTest() {
        YourApplication.main(new String[] {});
    }

}
```

Now Sonar is saying, this is tested!
(Kudos goes out to: Robert @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/41775613/863403)

Comment: Do not write tests to satisfy tools or target numbers. That is where the purpose of TDD and unit testing is lost. This answer is a bad pointer.