# Elegant method to compare an array of strings to another array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Question: **How can I elegantly compare an array of strings to another array of strings thus returning an array of non-matching strings**

```
var master = ['1','2','3','4']
var versioned = ['1a','2','3b','4']
var errorLog = []
var count = 0;
//this for loop doesn't work :(
for(var i = 0; i < versioned.length - 1; ++i ){
    for(var j = 0; j < master.length -1; ++j){
        if(versioned[i] === master[j]){
            console.log('cleared');
        }
        if(count === master.length){
            errorLog.push(versioned[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

### **loop will return ['1a', '3b'];**

I feel like `filter()` or `map()` or `reduce()` will do this but I'm unable to wrap my brain around this properly.

Comment: *Why, madame, if it so pleases the lady, would you please so carefully compare what I have in this basket, with what is in this very fine basket, and tell me, if you will, which is non-matching?*

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14853974 and http://phpjs.org/functions/array_diff/

Comment: @MaratTanalin it's not returning a true false of the diff.  It's returning an array of the non matching strings.

Comment: If you're only doing it one-sided like that, this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/8g1y2wdf/1

Comment: The compiler or runtime does not care if something is "elegant".  So what do you actually mean? Faster? Less code? Something else?  This question is way too broad as it is.

Comment: @JK I really meant just to make it work.  I did a huge forloop and it was pretty ugly with continues and breaks.  Luckily filiter() made it pretty elegant.

Comment: @jk - [*Take your stinking paws off me you damn dirty code!*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/184618/451969)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var master = ['1','2','3','4'];
var versioned = ['1a','2','3b','4'];

function diff(needle, haystack){
  return needle.filter(function(item){
    return !~haystack.indexOf(item); 
  });
}

console.log(diff(versioned, master)); //["1a", "3b"];
```

`~` NOTing any number equals -(x + 1). so ~-1 becomes 0, which is the only falsy.

`~master.indexOf(item)` is the same as `master.indexOf(item) !== -1`

Comment: That's "elegant" for you, @MatthewHarwood.

Comment: @JaredFarrish the !~ makes me happy :) cuz it's pretty.

Comment: I like to give ~ a use, so it doesn't feel lonely.

Comment: Lord God, our savior, please take mercy on our poor piteous souls. Amen.

Comment: my -1 question hurts my feelings :(