# Strange definitions of TRUE and FALSE macros

Tags: c++, c, macros, boolean, obfuscation

I have seen the following macro definitions in a coding book.

```
#define TRUE  '/'/'/'
#define FALSE '-'-'-'
```

There was no explanation there.

Please explain to me how these will work as `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

Comment: I think it's just a funny way to define TRUE as 1 and FALSE as 0

Comment: Note that this is a terrible idea without brackets around those expressions. I mean it's a terrible idea *with* them, but without you're just asking for a long night of debugging.

Comment: May I know the coding book you are referencing?

Comment: Note that there is no point to define TRUE and FALSE in C++, since you already have `true` and `false`. Nothing stops you, of course, from defining TRUE as 1, FALSE as 0 and perhaps MAYBE as 2.

Comment: I hope that book included this as an example of bad or deliberately obscure code.

Comment: I feel these could have been written in far more creative ways. How about `#define FALSE "hello" <:'\xF'??''\xA':>`

Comment: @DanielDaranas There's no point in defining them in C either, just include stdbool.h.

Comment: That is just so appallingly bad:(

Comment: Why do people things like this ? Or was it for an obfuscated C program contest?

Comment: Save for parentheses, I think it's funny. IDK what's unreadable about this, unlike Lundin's example. Obfuscated C program contest entries contain much "worse" techniques.

Comment: `#define TRUE 0??!??! "wtf"`  Ok I'll stop now :)

Comment: `#define FALSE ("1"??(1??))`

Comment: @Daniel: Shouldn't one rather define MAYBE as 0.5?

Comment: @Kaiserludi `'/'/'/'`, but I was assuming only integer values were allowed.

Comment: @Daniel:
Another idea would be to rand()%2 define MAYBE as rand()%2, so that is is sometimes == TRUE and sometimes == FALSE.

Comment: Aside from the lack of parentheses, these macros are very clever. Note that "very clever" is an insult.

Comment: @Lundin: If you're stuck using a pre-C99 implementation that doesn't support `<stdbool.h>`, you can use `typedef enum { false, true } bool;`

Comment: Very funny macro. Can we have the name of the book?

Comment: Apparently whoever wrote 1 and 0 that way had too much time on his hands and no consideration for how these macros were going to be used in expressions.

Comment: Why is `TRUE` being defined specifically as `1`, instead of a more general `!FALSE`?

Comment: It's not more general, it's just longer.

Comment: This is an alternative way to define boolean values when particular keys are broken on your keyboard.  For those who mention the lack of parenthesis, how would one even type ')' when they can't already type '0'?

Comment: @Panzercrisis: presumably because `!FALSE` is (on an ASCII system) `-45` due to the afore-mentioned missing parentheses. Maybe the author tried your idea but couldn't figure out why it didn't work ;-)

Comment: Which book?  Enquiring minds want to know.

Comment: Was it a C coding book, or a C++ coding book?

Comment: ISTR that in C, true is !0, not 1. So these definitions are both bad and half-wrong.

Comment: **In what coding book did you see these macro definitions?**

Comment: @Panzercrisis: `!FALSE` is no more general than `1`. Given that `FALSE` is `0`, `!FALSE` is `1` by definition.

Comment: @TMN: `!0` has exactly the same value as `1`. (Any non-zero value is considered "true" when used in a condition, but that's not what the `!` operator means.)

Comment: That's the closest I've seen to `#define TRUE FALSE //Happy debugging suckers` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered)

Comment: @Bradley **see the answer I posted for historical information**

Comment: But where is FileNotFound? http://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_

Answer (score 382, accepted):

Let's see: `'/' / '/'` means the `char` literal `/`, divided by the `char` literal `'/'` itself. The result is one, which sounds reasonable for `TRUE`.

And `'-' - '-'` means the `char` literal `'-'`, subtracted from itself. This is zero (`FALSE`).

There are two problems with this: first, it's not readable. Using `1` and `0` is absolutely better. Also, as  TartanLlama and KerrekSB have pointed out, if you are ever going to use that definition, please do add parentheses around them so you won't have any surprises:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRUE  '/'/'/'
#define FALSE '-'-'-'

int main() {
        printf ("%d\n", 2 * FALSE);
        return 0;
}
```

This will print the value of the `char` literal `'-'` (45 on my system).

With parentheses:

```
#define TRUE  ('/'/'/')
#define FALSE ('-'-'-')
```

the program correctly prints zero, even though it doesn't make much sense to multiply a truth value by an integer, but it's just an example of the kind of unexpected bugs that could bite you if you don't parenthesize your macros.

Comment: It actually make sense to multiply with truth value. For examle indentation*should_indent will result in either 0 or indentation based on whether should_indent without branching. (I guess that this is bad example, when working with text single branching does not matter, (I've seen this technique in shaders and in XPATH (both too different and i don't remeber exact form))

Comment: Alpedar -- but it doesn't *conceptually* and matehmatically make senso to do so -- in this case it would be clearer (and conceptually make sense) to use an `if` instead of multiplying `TRUE` by an integer.

Comment: Logical negation might be implemented as `notx = TRUE- x;` and works fine. Except that `TRUE-FALSE` is -44 (assuming ASCII)

Comment: @MarcWittke: Well, people who abuse the C preprocessor with broken macros like these will soon be without friends.  It's well known that simple text substitution of things that aren't rigorously guarded with parens can create extremely non-obvious breakage, which is why C++ introduces so many ways to do things *without* the C preprocessor, like templates and `static const bool TRUE = true;`.  (Although this definition actually has a type of `int`, not `bool`.)

Answer (score 90):

It's just another way of writing

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
```

The expression `'/'/'/'` will divide the char value of `'/'` by itself, which will give 1 as a result.

The expression `'-'-'-'` will substract the char value of `'-'` from itself, which will give 0 as a result.

Brackets around the whole `define` expressions are missing though, which can lead to errors in the code using these macros. [Jay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34062687/3854322) adresses that pretty well.

An example of "real-life" scenario where forgetting the brackets can be harmful is the combined use of these macros with a C-style cast operator. If someone decides to cast these expressions to `bool` in C++ for instance:

```
#include <iostream>

#define TRUE  '/'/'/'
#define FALSE '-'-'-'

int main() {
    std::cout << "True: " << (bool) TRUE << std::endl;
    std::cout << "False: " << (bool) FALSE << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here's what we get:

```
True: 0
False: -44
```

So `(bool) TRUE` would actually evaluate to `false`, and `(bool) FALSE` would evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 44):

It is equivalent to writing

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
```

What the expression `'/'/'/'` actually does is dividing the character `/` (whatever its numeric value is) by itself, so it becomes `1`.

Similarly, the expression `'-'-'-'` subtracts the character `-` from itself and evaluates to `0`.

It would be better to write

```
#define TRUE ('/'/'/')
#define FALSE ('-'-'-')
```

to avoid accidental change of values when used with other higher-precedence operators.

Answer (score 35):

[Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34062687/1119701) already answered why the values of these expressions are `0` and  `1`.

For history sake, these expressions `'/'/'/'` and `'-'-'-'` come from one of the entries of [1st International Obfuscated C Code Contest in 1984](http://www.ioccc.org/years.html#1984):

```
int i;main(){for(;i["]<i;++i){--i;}"];read('-'-'-',i+++"hell\
o, world!\n",'/'/'/'));}read(j,i,p){write(j/p+p,i---j,i/i);}
```

(Link to the program [here](http://www.ioccc.org/1984/anonymous.c), there is a hint of what this program does in the IOCCC page above.)

Also if I remember correctly these expressions as obfuscated macros for `TRUE` and `FALSE` were also covered in ["Obfuscated C and Other Mysteries"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471578053) book by Don Libes (1993).

Answer (score 8):

It is a hilarious way of writing macros for `True` and `False`.

As many explanations have been provided `/` means a 1-byte number(as per ASCII) when divided by itself it gives you `1` which will be treated as `True` and likewise  `-` is again a byte number when subtracted the same value it gives you `0` which will be interpreted as `false`

```
#define TRUE  '/'/'/'
#define FALSE '-'-'-'
```

hence we can replace `/` or `-` with any char we like, for example:

```
#define TRUE  '!'/'!'
#define FALSE 'o'-'o'
```

Will keep the same meaning as the original expression.

Answer (score 6):

Let's start with true. You can read it as `'/' / '/'`, which means "character '/' divided by character '/'". Since each character, in C, is a numeric value (on one byte), it can be read as "the ASCII value of character '/' divided by the ASCII value of that same character", which means 1 (because, obviously, x/x is 1). Hence, `TRUE` is 1.

For `FALSE`, its the same reasoning: `'-'-'-'` reads `'-' - '-'`, i.e "the ASCII value of '-' minus the ASCII value of '-'", which is 0. Hence, `FALSE` is 0.

This is a nasty way to state the obvious.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASCII.

Comment: @KerrekSB, in practice, yes, it does, unless you happen to develop on a very specific architecture, which is probably not relevant to OP's question.

Comment: @Fabien: It doesn't *depend* on ASCII. `'/'/'/'` is 1 for *any* valid character set, whether `'/' == 47` (as it is in ASCII), or `'/' == 97` (as it is in EBCDIC), or any other value.

Comment: @KeithThompson Well, not for _any_ character set - just the limited subset of those that do not map `'/' == 0` ;) which ASCII (or EBCDIC for that matter) are good examples of...

Comment: @Pawel: A conforming C implementation cannot map `'/'` to `0`. That value is reserved for the null character.

Comment: @KeithThompson :) If we're talking about ISO C then true - it defines null character as the zero byte, but still - you argued _any_ character set and nothing stops an arbitrary character set to designate null character as the visual glyph `'/'`

Comment: @Pawel: Sure, I could have been more explicit. But since the question is about C (and C++), that's what I meant by "any **valid** character set".

Comment: You are being pedantic.

Comment: @Matheus208 If Pawel was being pedantic, then that's ('-'-'-') since his point was based on an unstated condition; describing Keith's remarks as pedantic might be more ('/'/'/') but I'd call them "clarifying" (and with the added smileys "pedantic" definitely seems '/'-'/' to me). It may be ('-'/'-') that the comments taken together can be called pedantic but, 1) isn't that somewhat obligatory in this field? 2) they made me think; and 3) I'm a bit clearer on some things than I was.

And yes, I guess I'm being pedantic myself! (But I'm clearer about what "pedantic" means than I was! ;-)

Comment: @Matheus208: You say that like it's a bad thing.

Comment: Wow. This is so wonderful. @zhora, kudos for discussing the definition of "pedantic." I give all of you my deepest congratulations for your inerrant toils to improve the accuracy of the Internet.