# C# notepad program throws "Empty path name is not legal"

Tags: c#

I'm new to programming and I'm starting to create a simple notepad, with only 4 buttons (Open, Save, New and Font).

If I open or save I'm getting an error. This is my code:

```
        //Declare save as a new SaveFileDailog
        SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
        //Declare filename as a String equal to the SaveFileDialog's FileName
        String filename = save.FileName;
        //Declare filter as a String equal to our wanted SaveFileDialog Filter
        String filter = "Text Files|*.txt|All Files|*.*";
        //Set the SaveFileDialog's Filter to filter
        save.Filter = filter;
        //Set the title of the SaveFileDialog to Save
        save.Title = "Save";
        //Show the SaveFileDialog
        if (save.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Write all of the text in txtBox to the specified file
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, textBox1.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            //Return
            return;
        }//Declare save as a new SaveFileDailog
        SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
        //Declare filename as a String equal to the SaveFileDialog's FileName
        String filename = save.FileName;
        //Declare filter as a String equal to our wanted SaveFileDialog Filter
        String filter = "Text Files|*.txt|All Files|*.*";
        //Set the SaveFileDialog's Filter to filter
        save.Filter = filter;
        //Set the title of the SaveFileDialog to Save
        save.Title = "Save";
        //Show the SaveFileDialog
        if (save.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Write all of the text in txtBox to the specified file
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, textBox1.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            //Return
            return;
        }
```

### Update

Here is the error:

> Error: ArgumentException was unhandled.
> Empty path name is not legal

I get this if I open a text file. Then it highlighted this line code:
`textBox1.Text=System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename,System.Text.Encoding.Default)`.

And if I save nothing happens.

Comment: Looks like your code appears twice? What error do you get, and where in the code?

Comment: Tip - don't comment every single line. Use comments to *add* information instead of simply repeating what the code already states.

Comment: My favorite comment: "//Return return;"

Comment: May I suggest some good material on SO about code documentation:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209015/self-documenting-code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143429/whats-the-least-useful-comment-youve-ever-seen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I expect you should be reading the filename *after* the user has used the dialog:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(save.FileName, textBox1.Text);
```

Also - `SaveFileDialog` is `IDisposable`, so you should be "`using`" it...

```
using (SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog())
{
    // your code that involves "save"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the line

```
String filename = save.FileName;
```

inside the IF block. 
You are assigning to filename *before* the SaveDialog's property is set by the user.
You need to understand that this line does not create a permanent link between your `filename` variable and the `FileName` property of the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You get the filename from a SaveFileDialog **after** you call ShowDialog. You are setting filename beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you're saving with a blank filename - this changes during the call to .ShowDialog(), so it doesnt help that you've retrieved it beforehand.
You just need to pull out .FileName again after .ShowDialog.

Answer (score 0):

//To declare private int docno
//To declare private string filename
//To declare private bool modified=false;

```
          if (modify == true)
            {


                //this.Text = filename;

                filename = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                sw = new StreamWriter(filename);
                sw.Write(textBox1.Text);


                sw.Close();
                //modify = false;

            }

        else
            {
                saveFileDialog1.FileName = "Untitled" + docno.ToString() + ".txt";
                dresult = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                docno++;
            }
```